# React JS app using powerball-picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting started in reactJS and am building simple apps to get experience.  Right now I'm building a pretty basic app that generates powerball numbers and displays them when the user clicks a button.  My issue is I cannot seem to figure out how to take the data from the random.org API and display it as a string in my component.  I can see the numbers in the console perfectly fine and its working as intended there.  I'm pretty sure based on the errors React is giving me I need to convert the object data into an array.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Powerball from './Powerball/Powerball';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
state = {
    theNumbers: [
        {id: 'one', numbers: '', powerball: ''}
    ],
    showNumbers: false
}

powerballNumbersGetter = () => {
    const doesShow = this.state.showNumbers;
    this.setState({
        showNumbers: !doesShow
    });
}


render() {

    let numbers = null;
    if (this.state.showNumbers) {
        numbers = (
            <div>
                <Powerball/>
            </div>
        );
    }


    return (
        <div className="App">
            <p>TEST</p>
            <button

                onClick={this.powerballNumbersGetter}>Click to get Powerball 
               Numbers
            </button>
            {numbers}
        </div>
    );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Powerball.js

```
import React from 'react';

const powerball = (props) => {

var powerball = require('powerball-picker');
var apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" // obtained from 
Random.org API
var client = new powerball(apiKey);
client.pickPowerball(data => {
    console.log(data.numbers + " " + data.powerball);
});

return (
    <div>
        <p>You're Random Powerball numbers are (powerball numbers go here) 
and the powerball is (powerball
            here) </p>

    </div>
)
};

export default powerball;
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Since I'm not really sure what syntax need to be in the parenthesis, and I'm trying all different kinds, of things, I'm getting a lot of different error messages